# How to place Email-Ext groovy script on the jenkins file system

Tags: groovy, configuration, jenkins, email-ext

I need to dynamically modify the notification e-mail recipients based on the build, so I'm using a groovy script. I want this script to be available to all jobs, so I want it to reside on the Jenkins file system and not within each project. It can be either in the recipients fields (using ${SCRIPT,...}) or in the pre-send script. A short (fixed) script that evaluates the master script is also good, as long it is the same for all projects.

Answer (score 3):

You should try [**Config File Provider**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) plugin. It works together with the **Credentials** configuration of Jenkins.

- Go to **Manage Jenkins** > **Managed files**
- Click **Add a new Config**
- Select **Groovy file**
- Enter the contents of your script

Your script will now be saved centrally on Jenkins, available to master/slave nodes.

In your Job Configuration:

- Under **Build Environment**
- Check **Provide Configuration file**
- Select your configured groovy **File** from dropdown
- Set **Variable** with a name, for example: `myscript`

Now, anywhere in your job, you can say `${myscript}` and it will refer to absolute **location** of the file on filesystem (it will be somewhere in Jenkins dir).

Comment: Hi guys,
I tried exactly this. Unfortunately the script seems to be deleted before Email-Ext can access it.
Any idea?
15:52:14 provisoning config files...
-> 15:52:14 copy managed file [CPI_Emailscript_Groovy] to file:/tmp/config4504079314751031710tmp
15:52:14 [OIP_PI-CPI_uidt7054_11.0_ci] $ /bin/sh -x /tmp/hudson8833997127231887496.sh
...
15:52:19 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
-> 15:52:19 Deleting 1 temporary files
15:52:19 Sending email for trigger: Always
-> 15:52:19 groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: config4504079314751031710tmp for class: Script1

Comment: @Beasly after the file is brought over the first time, trying copying it manually to workspace (as one of the first build steps), then let Email-Ext access the one from workspace.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Strange is that it doesn't recognize the object "msg" anymore, when it tries to execute the script. If I paste it directly into "Pre-send Script" it works. Do you have an idea here too?

Comment: Seems not to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36572245/email-ext-objects-in-groovy-script-as-file/36647733#36647733

Answer (score 0):

My impression it that you would probably want to completely switch to Jenkins pipelines where the entire job is groovy file (Jenkinsfile) in the root of the repository.

Email-Ext already supports it even if it may be lacking some documentation.
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/