# Email-Ext objects in groovy script as file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, email-ext

My question is kind of a follow up of this:
[How to place Email-Ext groovy script on the jenkins file system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760914/how-to-place-email-ext-groovy-script-on-the-jenkins-file-system)

**Here is my situation:**
I have a groovy script which constructs the email which will be send.
This works fine as long as I have the script directly written (the code) in:

> Pre-send Script

---

If I take this script, place it in the Jenkins filesystem(...jenkins\email-templates) as: **email-presend.groovy** and I try to call it with:

```
  <presendScript>${SCRIPT, script="email-presend"}</presendScript>
```

I get the error message, that I can't access the message object:

> Script1.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'or' @ line 1, column 17.
>      Error in script or template: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: msg for class: Script1

Code on the line:

```
  msg.addHeader("X-Priority", "1 (Highest)"); 
  msg.addHeader("Importance", "High");
```

---

Am I missing something obvious, since I can't find any code snippet which did this?
I want to use the javax.mail.Message msg which is available if the code is directly in jenkins.

Comment: Nobody had this problem? How did the rest write into the email trough groovy?

Comment: Try using SCRIPT(script: "email-presend") instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems like it's not possible according to this post:
[Email-ext comment](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext%20plugin?focusedCommentId=75893517#comment-75893517)

Too bad :(